Can I solve this with a static route?
Environment Summary
I have 2 VM's with the following, they are on different HOST
VM #1 has 2 NICs

IP Address 172.31.154.100  with a gateway of 172.31.154.1
IP Address 172.31.177.200  with a gateway of 172.31.177.1

VM #2 has 1 NICs

IP Address 172.31.154.101  with a gateway of 172.31.154.1

On VM #1, when I ping 10.10.20.20 it is successful, because it goes out via 172.31.177.1
On VM #2, when I ping 10.10.20.20 it does not respond
Problem
On VM #2 I want to be able to connect to 10.10.20.20, but the Gateway 172.31.177.1 that has the allowed outbound to 10.10.20.20 is on VM #1 on a different Host.
I thought I would be able to create a static route on VM #2 such that the traffic to 10.10.20.20 can be redirected to through VM #1 and out via VM #1's 177.1 interface.  I did this by using the following route.  However this does not appear to work.
route add 10.10.20.20 MASK 255.255.255.255 172.31.154.100

Question
Can this scenario be resolved using a static route?  Note:  This is not a firewall issue with VM #2.

The network structure is thing that is independent from the physical, so it is not important about VMs and hosts; in your case, based on your information, it's something like
[VM2] 172.31.154.101 -+- 172.31.154.100 [VM1] 172.31.177.200 ---
                      |                             |
                 172.31.154.1 [gw2]           172.31.177.1 [gw1] ...
                                                                  |
                                                            10.10.20.20 [target]

Notice that it's not "a network has a gateway", but "a host has a gateway" which just means the default route. By default, VM2 sends traffic via 172.31.154.1, and it is unknown if it can send packets further to 10.10.20.20 or it is allowed, and that 10.10.20.20 has the route back.
You can solve the problem by routing VM2 via VM1, with the following conditions:

VM1 needs to have IPv4 forwarding enabled
One of the following

either all the systems between VM1 and target (inclusive) need to have the correct route back to 172.31.154.101 (this is preferred)
or VM1 need to perform masquerading (NAT) hiding VM2 behind its own IP address, to which there is already a working route



The best of all, however, is to have the correct routing on gateways. The whole idea of specialized networking systems is to hide the complexity of network, so at least the networking on the target systems can be simple. So, what I would do in your case, is to ensure the connection and routing between gateways or somewhere behind them so 10.10.20.20 or whatever would be directly accessible from either VM, without any additional tricks.
